# Filling column with values based on a sub query

Tags: mysql

I can't quite get my head around this particular problem, and I'm hoping you can help. I'm not tooooo bad at MySQL, but definately still a beginner. To save your time, I've broken the problem down to its barest elements. Any further info you need, just let me know what it is and I'll pop it straight up.

I have 3 tables: animal, owner, and region

The animal table holds all the relevant data about each animal, as well as an OwnerID column, referencing the ID column of the owner table.
The owner table is similar, and holds a RegionID column (as part of each owner's address), referencing the ID column of the region table.
I wish to create a column on the animal table, logging the RegionID of its owner. Is there an UPDATE I can run which would copy this data over? If anyone could talk me through the process I'd be most grateful.

My ideal end-result is to be able to search for animals based on location (a location assumed from the location of its owner). A column with the RegionID's in the animal table will allow me (at my level of ability) to do this simply and as part of further queries

#EDIT

Base Query:

```
$base= "SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.Prefix, CONCAT_WS(' ', p.Prefix, p.Name) AS ProfileName, 
        p.LocalRegNumber, p.GenderID, p.RegulatorID,
        p.ColourID, prm_colour.Name AS Colour, p.origColour,
        p.DiluteID, prm_dilute.Name AS Dilute,
        p.ModifierID, prm_modifier.Name AS Modifier,
        p.PatternID, prm_pattern.Name AS Pattern,
        p.DateofBirth, p.DateofDeath,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.DateofBirth) AS bYear, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.DateofDeath) AS dYear,
        p.SireReg, p.DamReg,
        p.OwnerID, p.BreederID,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', s.Prefix, s.Name) AS SireName,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', d.Prefix, d.Name) AS DamName,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', o.Firstname, o.Lastname) AS OwnerName,
        CONCAT_WS(' ', b.Firstname, b.Lastname) AS BreederName,
        prm_gender.Name AS Gender
                FROM profiles AS p
                    LEFT JOIN profiles AS s
                        ON p.SireReg = s.LocalRegNumber
                    LEFT JOIN profiles AS d
                        ON p.DamReg = d.LocalRegNumber
                            LEFT JOIN prm_colour
                                ON p.ColourID = prm_colour.ID
                            LEFT JOIN prm_dilute
                                ON p.DiluteID = prm_dilute.ID
                            LEFT JOIN prm_modifier
                                ON p.ModifierID = prm_modifier.ID
                            LEFT JOIN prm_pattern
                                ON p.PatternID = prm_pattern.ID
                    LEFT JOIN prm_gender
                                ON p.GenderID = prm_gender.ID
                            LEFT JOIN contacts AS o
                                ON p.OwnerID = o.ClientRef
                            LEFT JOIN contacts AS b
                                ON p.BreederID = b.ClientRef
                                 ";
```

I then pass form data to get which filters are applied (location, age, etc.). As an example, if searching by owner:

```
$where = "WHERE (p.OwnerID = '$ownedby')";
```

I then construct the query:

```
$complete=$base.$where;
$q= mysql_query($complete);
```

Comment: don't use UPDATE to copy the information. use JOINs to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you *could* copy that information over to your `animal` table, but wouldn't you be better off just using a `JOIN` when you need perform your search?

```
SELECT * FROM animal
  INNER JOIN owner ON animal.owner_id = owner.id
  INNER JOIN region ON owner.region_id = region.id
WHERE region.name = "myregion";
```

if you need to access this query a lot, you could consider making a `VIEW` from this query, too.

Comment: This is how I would normally have done it, but beacuse of the circumstances of my query (static base query + where clauses constructed via PHP from search vars) I need the work done in the WHERE clause - I'll attempt the IN solution proposed by ypercube.

Comment: if you must do it that way (and it sounds like a bad idea, to be honest), you could consider creating a `VIEW`, and querying against that instead of directly against the table.

Comment: @Eamonn: Why can't you use the `JOIN` query with PHP?

Comment: Having a bit of a facepalm moment about that myself... :S Have a look at the edits and see what you think, but I think that's what I will end up having to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to and you shouldn't do that. There is no need for the additional `RegionId` column in `Animal` table. To seacrh for Animals in a certain Region, say "Texas", use this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Animal AS a
WHERE OwnerId IN
      ( SELECT OwnerId
        FROM Owner
        WHERE RegionID IN
              ( SELECT RegionId
                FROM Region
                WHERE RegionArea = 'Texas'           --- example
              )
      )
```

or (usually better for performance):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Animal AS a
  JOIN Owner AS o
    ON o.OwnerId = a.OwnerId
  JOIN Region AS r
    ON r.RegionId = o.RegionId
WHERE r.RegionArea = 'Texas'
```

---

The reasons you don't want to copy the data are the same reasons that **[normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)** is good:

> The objectives of normalization beyond 1NF (First Normal Form) were stated as follows by Codd:
>
> 1. To free the collection of relations from undesirable insertion, update and deletion dependencies;
> 2. To reduce the need for restructuring the collection of relations as new types of data are introduced, and thus increase the life span of application programs;
> 3. To make the relational model more informative to users;
> 4. To make the collection of relations neutral to the query statistics, where these statistics are liable to change as time goes by.

---

Think of what should happen in your scenario, if an Owner moved to another Region. Besides his own `RegionId`, all the related Animal rows would have to be updated, too.

You could also have (by mistake) an animal with a different `RegionId` than it's owner's.

Comment: Looks great! That could fit my bill just right actually. I haven't really used the IN clause that much, so wasn't used to thinking of it as an option. I'll try it out and accept with gratitude. Out of interest, coz I'm learning, how could the values be written over if I needed to do so?

Comment: depending on the exact version of MySQL, using joins instead of subqueries is _far_ preferable

Comment: @simon: I know. Especially when using `IN` inside `IN` sub-subqueries. But it's a more clear query. And future versions of MySQL will be able to "translate" one form to another.

Comment: yeah, the query-optimization engines tend to take care of all that these days, but from a pedagogical point of view, using joins is the more 'correct' way.

Comment: @Eamonn: You could `UPDATE Aminal a JOIN Owner o ON o.OwnerId = a.OwnerId SET a.RegionId = o.RegionId`

Comment: Ta for that. still trying your IN solution, but it's not working for me yet (my fault entirely!). I'll edit my question to include the base query I'm using, as well as the PHP generated clauses.

Comment: @simon: I have never encountered the opinion that `JOIN` is more correct than `IN`. But you are right, if you mean that MySQL optimizer is known to not make the best plan for `IN` subqueries, while other systems do a far better job in (automatic) query rewriting.

Comment: Went with Simon's solution in the end. It works, I get it, and it seems the soundest. Thx for your links and advice though, very helpful!